# How to specify javaagent for Android?

Tags: android, jvm, aspectj, jvm-arguments

Is there any way to specify -javaagent argument when starting an APK on Android?
I'd like to specify aspectj's aspectjweaver.jar to java vm argument for a loading time instrumentation.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

No. The Dalvik VM running application code in Android is not a JVM.

Android does, however support instrumentation through [Instrumentation classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html). You may be able to find a port of aspectj for Android that already supports this, though you may also need to write it yourself.

Don't forget to [register your instrumentation class in your manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/instrumentation-element.html) if you go down this route.

Comment: Thank you Tanis. I will give it a try. Does instrumentation support writing my own class loader?