# Load time weaving using aspectj in android

Tags: android, aop, aspectj

Is it possible to use aop.xml i.e. load time weaving in an android application?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not an Android developer, so I can only answer from an AspectJ perspective.

- If you can start a JVM with `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` parameter, you should be fine. If not, you have a problem with LTW because it is based on the weaving agent being loaded before the application classes are.
- In that case just switch to CTW (compile time weaving) and, if necessary, use `if()` pointcuts to make aspect activation dynamic, if you do not want the aspect code to be active at all times. But if they should be always active CTW is simpler and faster than LTW anyway.

**Update:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19522610/1082681) seems to imply that `-javaagent` is unavailable on Android, but I cannot say if this is true and still valid as of November 2014.